# How do I generate multiple inputs in formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, formtastic

Adapted from [the nested form Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), I have:

In my model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fields
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :fields
end

class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

In my controller

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  4.times { @post.fields.build }

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

In my view

```
<%= semantic_form_for @post do |f| %>

  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
  <% end %>

  <%= semantic_fields_for :fields do |h| %>
    <%= h.input :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.buttons do %>
    <%= f.commit_button %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that this only generates one :field input even though i ran @post.fields.build four times. I can't figure out how to generate multiple inputs so the user can enter multiple fields.

Sorry if this is obvious but I'm new to Rails and pretty new to programming overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nested form ain't correct
Change `<%= semantic_fields_for :fields do |h| %>` to 
`<%= f.inputs :for => :fields do |h|%>`